# Return from async/await function inside async/await function (Puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

```
    let hi = main("1404339566");
    console.log(hi)    

    function main(isbn) {
      return puppeteer.launch({ headless: true  }).then(async browser => {
          return "Text on page found";
      })
    }
```

I am trying to get this to print "Text on page found". I have tried many configurations of await in different places but can't get it working. Why does this return `Promise { <pending> }` and not `"Text on page found"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })` actually returns you a `Promise`, thats why you are able to attach a `.then` to it.

Now inside the `.then`, whatever you return is still going to be finally wrapped inside a `Promise` and returned to you.

There are two ways to go ahead.

One way you can solve this is,

```
main("1404339566").then(value => console.log(value);

function main(isbn) {
  return puppeteer.launch({ headless: true  }).then(async browser => {
      return "Text on page found";
  })
}
```

Since the return value of your `main` function is a `Promise` you can read the value it contains inside a `then` callback.

Other way to handle this would be to use `async await` again. Like this. This code might or might not change slightly depending on your actual use case.

```
function main(isbn) {
  return puppeteer.launch({ headless: true  }).then(async browser => {
      return "Text on page found";
  })
}

console.log(await main("1404339566"));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! Could you provide an example of what using "async await" again would look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
main("1404339566").then(res => console.log(res);
```